# Auto start Virtualbox VM on Windows 10 boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox

I want to automatically start Virtualbox VM on Windows 10 boot, preferable without additional programs. Even if user is not logged in.
I tried several options:
Created VM shortcut (Right click on the VM in the list and select Create Shortcut on Desktop) and then copied it to:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

And also tried to copy it to user dependent StartUp dir (windows+r, type shell:startup, enter)
But recently installed Windows 10 with latest updates executes content of folder only when I log in to PC. Worth to mention that I have also other Windows 10 installation and there it works, it seems like windows pre log in the only existing user. And when I log in VM already running (with head/window). On recently installed windows it does not work like that (also has only one user).
In both cases users are "offline".

I also tried to use Windows Task Scheduler:
[image: General]
[image: Trigger]
[image: Action]

```
--comment "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS bub" --startvm "{GUID}" --type headless
```

If I set "Start in" it does not work at all.
[image: Conditions]
[image: Settings]

It works correctly only in case of restart. In case of shutdown and then cold start - it does not start the VM for some reason. I do not see any messages in Event Viewer / Windows Logs. I cannot figure out the reason why it does not want to start.

Enabled History and according to it in case of cold start it does not even tries to start the task (no entries at in history for cold start time). What could be the issue?

Windows 10 version:

[image: Windows 10 version]

I know that similar question already exists: [How do you configure Virtualbox VM to autostart after Windows-10 reboot?](https://superuser.com/questions/1027410/how-do-you-configure-virtualbox-vm-to-autostart-after-windows-10-reboot)

I tried variants from there and it does not work anymore and would like to revisit available options.
Do you have any thoughts?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to use Task scheduler is fine. However because of hibernation (which is enabled by default) it does not work on cold start. Hibernation should be disabled and it works for me as expected:

```
Run Command Prompt as Administrator
Execute following command:
powercfg.exe /h off
```

Answer (score 0):

### Question Highlight:

I want to automatically start Virtualbox VM on Windows 10 boot, ***preferable without additional programs. Even if user is not logged in.***

### Solution:

You can easily implement this as a Task via task scheduler that will run every time your system boots/starts **BEFORE** a user logs on.

Information on that can be found in my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67305645/5387389